# Software to popup a dialog box on Windows, initiated from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, remote-desktop

I have Linux machines.  My kid has a Windows machine (used only for gaming).  From my Linux laptop, I want to send an annoying dialog box that would display in the middle of the screen something like "Come down to eat supper!".  The dialog box would show up on top of his game.

When he is using a Linux machine to play on Steam, I remotely login (ssh) and run:

```
zenity --warning --text "${TEXT}" --title "${TITLE}" --width 800 --height 600
```

It works wonderfully.  Anybody has a suggestion on how to do the same on Windows, from my Linux machines?

I am searching for some free, ideally open source software, that would allow me to perform this task.  It could be two software solutions, one to remote login and another to show up a dialog box (the equivalent of zenity on Windows).  But it would be even better if there would be one client-server software that would do it all.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like **[howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185),** [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please explicitly state so and include how much are you willing to pay if needed. For a how-to, this question might better fit on SuperUser (make sure to read their `/help/on-topic` first for how to fit it).

Comment: @Izzy ... I agree that my question is borderline...  However, I am looking for the equivalent of the software I use on my platform (Linux) on another platform (Windows) which I am not familiar with.  I thought of putting it on another stackexchange site, but it is a software recommendation I am looking for, in the end.  But it is debatable, I agree.

Comment: Call me crazy but seems like you can just send him a steam message/voice call to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @st0le, it is an idea, but it is not a universal solution, as sometimes he does not play under steam.  I want a universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use `smbclient` with the `-M` or `--message` option to send a (short) message to a Windows machine.

Note that this may depend on pre-Active Directory "workgroup" level configuration, and it may not be in Win10 ...